# The method gettext() is undefined for the type list webelement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\K.Stas\\eclipse-workspace\\Components\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.kinopoisk.ru/lists/top250/");
    List<WebElement> allLinks = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("p[class='selection-film-item-meta__name']"));
    allLinks.get(new Random().nextInt(allLinks.size())).click();

    //here is a problem
    List<WebElement> str =  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h1[class='moviename-big']"));
    String name1 = str.getText().toString();

    System.out.println(name1);
}
```

}

I want a random movie to be selected from the list on the site and after the page has opened, the name of this movie will be displayed in the console. Can you help me! Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Str is a list so you first have to get the object,

for example:

```
List<WebElement> str =  driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("h1[class='moviename-big']"));
String name1 = str.get((int)(str.size() - 1)).getText(); 
System.out.println(name1);
```

Comment: Work! But if name of movie is composed of 2 words Like "Green Mile", appear error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 1
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
 at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:425)
 at Test.main(Test.java:19)

Comment: Test this: 

String name1 = str.get((int)(Math.random() * str.size() - 1)).getText();